# How to iterate through n amount of keys in a Typescript map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working with Typescript, and I have a map of many key-value pairs. I'm now trying to access only the 10 first key-value pairs in that map. I have a for-loop that goes through 10 iterations, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the key-value pairs from the map. I'm only iterating through the first key-value pair key 10 times right now. Is there another way to go through a map and only select the n amount of key-value pairs?

This is what I got:

```
let map = new Map([
    ["key1", "value1"],
    ["key2", "value2"],
    ...
]);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(map.keys().next().value);
}
```

Comment: `map.keys()` gives you a new iterator every time. You need to use the same iterator and get 10 values from it.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks got it working with creating a variable of the map.keys() and then using that inside the for-loop

Comment: You could also do `Array.from(map.keys()).slice(0,10)`. Here, `Array.from( map.keys() )` returns an array of keys in the Map. Replace `10` with any number of required keys to get the first `n` keys.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this but this question saved my time as I was dealing with weird issues with Office Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @VLAZ

> map.keys() gives you a new iterator every time. You need to use the same iterator and get 10 values from it

So this is how I changed up the code:

```
let map = new Map([
    ["key1", "value1"],
    ["key2", "value2"],
    ...
]);

let mapKeys = map.keys();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(mapKeys.next().value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#generator_functions) to help out in these situation by getting *up to* a number of items from an iterable.

```js
function* take(n, iterable) {
  for (const item of iterable){
    if (--n < 0) break;

    yield item;
  }
}


const m = new Map([
  ["a", 1],
  ["b", 2],
  ["c", 3],
  ["d", 4],
  ["e", 5]
]);
  
console.log(
  Array.from( take(3, m.keys()) ) //["a", "b", "c"]
);

for (const key of take(10, m.keys()) ) {
  console.log(`key: ${key}`); //"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
}
```

Written in TypeScript, the generator will look like this:

```js
function* take<T>(n: number, iterable: Iterable<T>): Generator<T> {
  for (const item of iterable){
    if (--n < 0) break;

    yield item;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mAVAAigQwNYFMA8AVAPgAowAuZMEAWwCMsAnAGmRigbRoBstyBJN+h274CASnIBxLGHZQ49EcgDeAKGTJg85EQgIAzlBZsqyOMCPsuWUavXqY5ogFonYZDmQAGUchr0smADcKmp2AJ4wWJwAJhZUweoAvirJIbpgBsgmALwUWADuyACyaAAOOAb0MGAA5syUtAzEANqhzQBEaO3MAIwAuoxt7TTdyABMA0MQowDMk+od0aMALPPIHVijAKx9Kn2iCcgq6Xpw3AB0nHA1RKEAgvSCYefA9HBURKiYWEQzzFTnbBhPREUQ+HwAeghHS6zGGo3a012BxCmno2hOhiBpnM6GwRB6nn+gKwwNB4OUoROZywl2uRAABkDyAASJRAxIMg7IKGdBEjOHTOFLOGbFJAA)